# User logs into Jira, but sees nothing - does not seem to actrually log in

Tags: jira

A user has project permissions, but cannot see anything after the login screen.  just this, and the Login option, as though he did not log in.  Any ideas?  It it hard to search for help on "jira issues"

[image]

Comment: just confirming the obvious: cookies & js for that user's browser are enabled and their browser security is otherwise configured correctly?

Comment: I can log in just fine with my account as can others. I tried this on chrome, which I use all the time and may have cookie issues.  then IE and FireFox, and they behave the same for that user.

Comment: @DanielWilliams, based on the screen capture, it appears that the login itself has failed. Could it be that the ur account exceeded the number of users allowed for your license?

Answer (score 0):

If this is with OnDemand JIRA then the user probably doesn't have Application Access to JIRA

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.  Someone was changing permissions and removed these users from the "users" group.  You must belong to this to use Jira at all.

[image]